# How to override given CMS-driven routes in SAP spartacus?

Tags: typescript, routes, url-routing, spartacus-storefront

Reading through the docs of spartacus, regarding the [customization of routing links](https://sap.github.io/spartacus-docs/adding-and-customizing-routes/) it seems like it is only possible to change those routes, that are routing to product, category, and brand pages. They state 'Content pages have a configurable URL in the CMS' and 'To add a new route, you simply add a new Content page in the CMS, and give it a page label'. However, there are content pages provided by spartacus (e.g. 'orders'), that already have a configured route. Here comes the problem.
My current account page is listed under the route '/account', but the orders-route points at '/my-account/orders'. Is there a way to override those routes coming from spartacus CMS pages?

I already created a new content page with my customized route:

```
;;orders                  ;/account/orders            ;Orders History                 ;AccountPageTemplate
```

And tried to simply add a custom routing config for that in my frontend:

```
  orders: {
    paths: ['account/orders'],
  }
```

and

```
{
    data: {
      pageLabel: 'orders',
      cxRoute: 'orders'
    },
    component: CmsPageComponent,
    canActivate: [CmsPageGuard],
    path: null
  }
```

This doesn't work. It just routes to '/' since it cant find a fitting mapping.
I hope some of you had a same problem and can provide an easy solution for this. If you need any more information or code, let me know. :)

Comment: Did you try to align the value of the field `pageLabel` in Spartacus route object with the `pageLabel` value that you have set in CMS? In other words, did you try changing the `pageLabel` in Spartacus to  `'account/orders'` or `'/account/orders'`? I'm not sure if it solves your issue, but just hinting by the way that `pageLabel` in Spartacus and `pageLabel` in CMS must be aligned. (+/- I don't remember if the leading slash is needed here or/and there.)

Comment: I think that the problem is there:
Configuration of lazy-loaded routes is currently not supported.
https://sap.github.io/spartacus-docs/configurable-routing/